# Symfony - Form Generation failure: Cannot fetch TableMap for undefined table

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, generator, propel

This is a curious issue.  I've had a project up and running for a while,
this only started when I added one new table to the schema.

These are the relevant schema descriptions.    Each table exsists and matches:

```
  comment:
    id:
    message:         longvarchar
    quote_id:
    reply_id:        { type: integer, foreignTable: comment, foreignReference: id}
    created_by:      { type: integer, foreignTable: sf_guard_user, foreignReference: id, onDelete: setnull }
    created_at:
    updated_at:

  quote:
    id:
    account_number:
    customer_name:
    ...
    created_at:
    updated_at:         

  contract
    id:
    account_number:  varchar(32)
    customer_name:   varchar(64)
    ...
    created_at:
    updated_at:

  contract_comment:
    id:
    contract_id:
    comment_id:
```

When I run ./symfony propel:build --all, it builds the model classes,
and starts to build the form classes, then it errors out saying:

> Cannot fetch TableMap for undefined
>   table: comment

However, it's abundantly clear that the table does exist.  If I remove
the contract_comment entry from the schema, and rebuild, the comments work fine.

I looked up the other users who ran into this error here, but none of their solutions
apply to my situation.

Comment: Hi, @Geoff! I would recommend you to use verbose syntax to describe your schema. Actually, sometimes automagic is not good as expected to be.

Comment: Probably a wise suggestion, especially in this case.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried re-naming the comment table to something else?
I had similar problems with a table named "project" because apparently that is a special word in Propel (?) when trying to build everything. Renaming it to jump_project or whatever solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem myself.

The solution was to update the composer autoloader to include the new table classes/bases/maps.